# Count same date result as one

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table :

[image]

when i count the entries of month January using the query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS entries FROM daily_call_reports WHERE Month(datetime_in)='01' AND emp_id='E0001'
```

I got the result 5.
But i want to count same date rows as one.. in the table there are two row of same date 2016-01-21. Now how to count these two row as one..

Comment: please post your desired output here that will make easy your requirements.

Comment: I update my  answer, try this now.

Answer (score 0):

> In a table, a column may contain many duplicate values; and sometimes
>   you only want to list the different (distinct) values.
>
> The DISTINCT keyword can be used to return only distinct (different)
>   values.

You have to use `DISTINCT` for counting the different rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(`datetime_in`, '%Y-%m-%d')) as entries  FROM daily_call_reports WHERE month(datetime_in)='01' AND emp_id='E0001'
```

Try this one and let me know.

Comment: @Frayne Konok it will not work ,because datetime_in field have different time with same date

Comment: got it, you have different time but same date.

Comment: @iSemanticsTechnology, if its works then you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select count(*)
from 
(SELECT distinct id,client_id,emp_id,...., CAST(re.datetime_in AS DATE) AS DATE_PURCHASED
FROM daily_call_reports re
WHERE Month(datetime_in)='01' AND emp_id='E0001')
```

Comment: The key is you need to convert the date time_in to the value just date, then use distinct to select the table. I think CAST(re.datetime_in AS DATE) should be work to convert